# How to get the difference of a MINUS/subtraction function in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, subtraction

I am working with a CSV file and I need 100+ numbers which are all different to equal the number 10. I would something like a cell to look like this: `76 - ("Unknown" Number) = 10`

The way the CSV file is set up, the first column is the item price (e.g `79.99`), and it needs to equal `69.99` in the sale column, which I am trying to edit, and it displays $10 on our site. We have different prices for each product.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is irrelevant to programming. Note: `X - Y = 10` means that `X - 10 = Y`.

Comment: Yes, I know. But that is not what I am asking. `76 - 10 != 10`. The way the CSV file is set up, the first column is the item price (e.g `$79.99`). We are doing a $10 sale. So I need the sale column to be `69.99` so it equals 10 on our site. Sorry, I should have stated this.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,A2:A-10))
```

[image]

Comment: it checks if A column contains something - if not it outputs nothing - if yes then it takes value in A column and subtracts 10 from it

Comment: Now that I am thinking about it, this question was not worth it... I was thinking of division remainder this whole time when I could have just subtracted 10...